# kernel of a surjective map of bundles on curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve. Let $L$ be a base point free line bundle on $C$ with $h^0(L)=2$ and suppose we know that the map $H^0(L) \otimes \mathcal O_C \to L$ is surjective. Then is it true that the kernel of this map is $L^*$?

Is there a quick argument to deduce kernels of such map?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: This is obviously false in general. Did you try any examples?

Comment: @KReiser, I have edited the question now . Is it true for $h^0(L)=2$? Does there exist a technique/recipe  to compute what the kernel is in such situation?

Comment: When $h^0(L)=2$, yes: take determinants. I would imagine this is a duplicate, but I have not quite found the right target yet.

Comment: @KReiser, thanks. Is it the case because section $2$ means kernel has to be of rank $1$?